# Vertically align image and nav item in navbar in Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to align an image and a nav-link vertically centre in Bootstrap 5. But the nav-link with button never aligns to the navbar and the other links.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU" />
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-dark">
<header>
    <nav b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-primary box-shadow mb-3 py-2">
        <div b-kcycjqi1p7 class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                Logo
            </a>
            <button b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li b-kcycjqi1p7 class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li b-kcycjqi1p7 class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/home/privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item d-inline-block">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button" >
                hello
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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&#x2B;Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3&#x2B;Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3&#x2B;Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDBtdJ1tdTF5EbpVV2Cgxsw687vTiori&#x2B;ntddEk8rQ&#x2B;W&#x2B;TbgbyT6Y9PrU&#x2B;r6p4nlc6PBHcRJJzvLEu4&#x2B;v8ASsuDS9Re582WCSacH5pQ&#x2B;cN0Oaw5fd1PPa6s2n1uSS9SMiaGAkHL8DntxXe22i2F0IPPnmnW5&#x2B;aN9m0EjqPwrzvT08Ua2ZhpHkQw2r&#x2B;QGdQCWB5NbkWu&#x2B;JPBt3HbeIXje3nUrDOhzg/iO9ZvBU&#x2B;ZNPX&#x2B;vM2&#x2B;pStzI07jTJooZLSzHm3UcuXmJJH&#x2B;6p6YxSRW3lzgSyupEe90wQRXR2sMTeRcPPdRs2NixyjbIG5Hy/5xTrsxm5NuSYxKxSQsOee2eta00o&#x2B;6iKdRw0PL2vYZvEUumzSyt9ptlmS5jc&#x2B;bHcYyCp9M9qoalHd&#x2B;INIF7G6jU7Xi9WE7HkA/iK&#x2B;o7kVgx3sbatM&#x2B;HEgZo0cnuOlJb389r4ka6RnSdlbaB3OK6dC3CzO48OQ3&#x2B;yzdNeTT4b2R3uEyOfVvT6fWtWPSBrdhd6dqOvNqUofdAH5CEc5ViTjI4yOOa47RvPvtJmkvbGQ2ce5knZSFBJwVDEY684rtPB/h99dlmFgpt7VoWSScnIDFCowccnpwPSsJuSdkerTlH2abL1uy6lodxLbzyGWFifLjILxoD1APXgdRUK&#x2B;KJdQWOQRLKU/dvOASA3QfjjvU2qQ32j6ZZajcRNaaqluLe9ixwSDgSAjgjIBz71zFlLPPJJ9jm8ieeTLozBEYdyB0yawlGNOyvY8Rx1OIsdDvtb1waVaxyG8urzbGNnCJyWcn0A5r6o0bQdD0iGODTtOt1aNApm8ob392bGSTjmuN&#x2B;Fnh8obzXLhNpZmt7fI&#x2B;YqD8zHI4yeOPSu3gnX7bdxiTgFVPI54yK6m&#x2B;h2Ju1yzf2sd/CbaVVMLDBUgEflS2FhbWSbYVwe4z/TpTBdD7WlqBhxEZcD0zgf1pt1ctJlIJBGVI3MRSdtxpjtTtdM1awe1v4EuYX/5Zkcn6d/xFcPL4W0vS9ZjuGkzY3EbR&#x2B;XIAwjccgbsemfyrtbeF5lF7udQ4yEGBlR0yeuD1wMda5/xxNHb6RbGeVoke5AQqM/wMeQc5FK13cVSKav1P/9k=" alt="Akshay Gollahalli" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark dropdown-menu-end">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item bg-danger" href="/microsoftidentity/account/signout">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the `hello` button. Is there a way to make then vertically aligned to other links? Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: To be sure, you are setting a doctype?

Comment: @Rob No I am not

Comment: [A doctype is required](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#the-doctype) of all current, modern web pages. Without one, you are in [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) and a strange, non-standard world you never want to be in and is the probably source of all your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navbar-nav` has `display: flex;` so you can use the `align-items-center` utility class to the `<ul>` element.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=47DEQpj8HBSa-_TImW-5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU" />
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 bg-dark">
<header>
    <nav b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-primary box-shadow mb-3 py-2">
        <div b-kcycjqi1p7 class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                Logo
            </a>
            <button b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul b-kcycjqi1p7 class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li b-kcycjqi1p7 class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li b-kcycjqi1p7 class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/home/privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link btn btn-danger" href="#" role="button" >
                hello
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,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&#x2B;Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3&#x2B;Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3&#x2B;Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDBtdJ1tdTF5EbpVV2Cgxsw687vTiori&#x2B;ntddEk8rQ&#x2B;W&#x2B;TbgbyT6Y9PrU&#x2B;r6p4nlc6PBHcRJJzvLEu4&#x2B;v8ASsuDS9Re582WCSacH5pQ&#x2B;cN0Oaw5fd1PPa6s2n1uSS9SMiaGAkHL8DntxXe22i2F0IPPnmnW5&#x2B;aN9m0EjqPwrzvT08Ua2ZhpHkQw2r&#x2B;QGdQCWB5NbkWu&#x2B;JPBt3HbeIXje3nUrDOhzg/iO9ZvBU&#x2B;ZNPX&#x2B;vM2&#x2B;pStzI07jTJooZLSzHm3UcuXmJJH&#x2B;6p6YxSRW3lzgSyupEe90wQRXR2sMTeRcPPdRs2NixyjbIG5Hy/5xTrsxm5NuSYxKxSQsOee2eta00o&#x2B;6iKdRw0PL2vYZvEUumzSyt9ptlmS5jc&#x2B;bHcYyCp9M9qoalHd&#x2B;INIF7G6jU7Xi9WE7HkA/iK&#x2B;o7kVgx3sbatM&#x2B;HEgZo0cnuOlJb389r4ka6RnSdlbaB3OK6dC3CzO48OQ3&#x2B;yzdNeTT4b2R3uEyOfVvT6fWtWPSBrdhd6dqOvNqUofdAH5CEc5ViTjI4yOOa47RvPvtJmkvbGQ2ce5knZSFBJwVDEY684rtPB/h99dlmFgpt7VoWSScnIDFCowccnpwPSsJuSdkerTlH2abL1uy6lodxLbzyGWFifLjILxoD1APXgdRUK&#x2B;KJdQWOQRLKU/dvOASA3QfjjvU2qQ32j6ZZajcRNaaqluLe9ixwSDgSAjgjIBz71zFlLPPJJ9jm8ieeTLozBEYdyB0yawlGNOyvY8Rx1OIsdDvtb1waVaxyG8urzbGNnCJyWcn0A5r6o0bQdD0iGODTtOt1aNApm8ob392bGSTjmuN&#x2B;Fnh8obzXLhNpZmt7fI&#x2B;YqD8zHI4yeOPSu3gnX7bdxiTgFVPI54yK6m&#x2B;h2Ju1yzf2sd/CbaVVMLDBUgEflS2FhbWSbYVwe4z/TpTBdD7WlqBhxEZcD0zgf1pt1ctJlIJBGVI3MRSdtxpjtTtdM1awe1v4EuYX/5Zkcn6d/xFcPL4W0vS9ZjuGkzY3EbR&#x2B;XIAwjccgbsemfyrtbeF5lF7udQ4yEGBlR0yeuD1wMda5/xxNHb6RbGeVoke5AQqM/wMeQc5FK13cVSKav1P/9k=" alt="Akshay Gollahalli" width="40" height="40" class="rounded-circle">
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark dropdown-menu-end">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item bg-danger" href="/microsoftidentity/account/signout">Sign out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution is invalid. Your solution is non-standard HTML and done using quirks mode and no web page should be in quirks.

Comment: Which part of my answer is non-standard HTML?

Comment: "Quirks mode" is non-standard. See my comment under the question.